# ssh client with paramiko (python)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, attributeerror

```
# sshpy v1 by s0urd
# simple ssh client 
# irc.gonullyourself.org 6667 #code

import paramiko
import os

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
privatekey = os.path.expanduser('/home/rabia/private')
mkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekey)
ssh.connect('78.46.172.47', port=22, username='s0urd', password=None, pkey=mkey)

while True:
      pick = raw_input("sshpy: ")
      stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(pick)
      print stdout.readlines()   
      ssh.close()
```

When I try to run more then 1 command I get this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it's because at the end of the `while` loop you do `ssh.close()` (thus closing the session).

Comment: @zeekay Thanks.. I also have another question, it seems I cannot change directories, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: `sftp = ssh.open_sftp(); sftp.chdir('path')`

Comment: Docs: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html#chdir. It should work unless the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @zeekay Im doing this: 
`def sftp_chdir():
     sftp = ssh.open_sftp(); 
     sftp.chdir('/home/s0urd/web')`

Comment: The `sftp` client is changing directories, use it to interact, add/move/remove files, etc.